# Ajax call always returns in error from controller Magento 2

Tags: json, ajax, controller, magento2

From my controller, I return a JSON data to my Ajax call but it always goes in the error section, even when it's not an error.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/yxcustomer/index/emailpreferences',
    data: {"category1": category1,"category2":category2 , "category3":category3,"category4":category4,"category5":category5,"category6":category6,"category7":category7,
           "latest1":latest1,"latest2":latest2,"latest3":latest3,"latest4":latest4,
           "frequency":frequency,
           "email":email,"firstName":firstName , "lastName":lastName},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("data response success prefe " + JSON.stringify(data));

    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("data response error prefe " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

`Controller code`

```
 protected $resultJsonFactory;



 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
) {
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


 public function execute()
  {
    try{
       return  $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['success' => true,'contact'=>json_encode($contact) ,'message' => $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage("Successfully updated email preferences")]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return  $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['success' => false,'message' => $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('Email preferences cannot be updated')]);            
    }
}
```

Still that success code

```
$this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['success' => true,'contact'=>json_encode($contact) ,'message' => $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage("Successfully updated email preferences")])
```

Always goes in ajax error part

```
error: function (error) {}
```

the response in Ajax is

> data response error prefe {"readyState":4,"responseText":"reading contacts with equalto filter\n{\"success\":true,\"contact\":\"{"id":"c74668c8-e886-4592-8950-273a7a6ab72d","email":"an@gmail.com","status":"onboarding","msgPref":"html","source":"api","customSource":"source","created":"2019-03-20T13:10:40-04:00","modified":"2019-03-21T03:44:36-04:00","deleted":false,"fields":[{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c10d","content":""},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c10f","content":"Fluid"},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c10e","content":"Men"},{"fieldId":"91c22871-0947-4f63-b067-4290ce18c0a0","content":"Anupam"},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c111","content":""},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c110","content":""},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c113","content":"All"},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c112","content":""},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c115","content":""},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c114","content":"New Arrivals"},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c117","content":"Never Mind"},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c116","content":""},{"fieldId":"0bc403e9000000000000000000000005c0e8","content":""},{"fieldId":"2b0a63f9-cb2d-4fc7-bcc5-06b30b59f8db","content":"singh"}],"numSends":0,"numBounces":0,"numOpens":0,"numClicks":0,"numConversions":0,"conversionAmount":0}\",\"message\":{}}","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

What am I doing wrong, is there some Magento 2 issue?

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, the `$resultJsonFactory` is used to return the data in JSON format, and you are already doing that which is correct. But, the response goes into the error function of your AJAX request because from the controller, you are encoding the `$contact` data again in JSON. So, just remove the `json_encode` like below:

```
return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData([
    'success' => true,
    'contact' => $contact,
    'message' => $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage("Successfully updated email preferences")
]);
```

instead of:

```
return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData([
    'success' => true,
    'contact' => json_encode($contact),
    'message' => $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage("Successfully updated email preferences")
]);
```